# Android: some devices require WRITE_SETTINGS permission?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-permissions

I'm finding some instances, on some devices but far from all, where my app will crash when trying to open a [configuration Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring) for my [App Widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html).  Crash reports include the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.x.y.z/com.x.y.A}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
```

Of course, I've tried adding the following to my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

But this does nothing to stop the crashes, with the same messages about requiring `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS`.

I'm at a loss... it's saying that this permission is needed, and I'm granting that permission, but still the crashes.  Furthermore, I'm not sure why this is only an issue with some devices (a minority) and not others.  Why is it required at all?  In my configuration Activity I write to and read from [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) but this hasn't caused any permissions issues until recently.

These are the devices that have been sending in crash reports:

```
Galaxy Note3 (hlte) running Android 5.0
Galaxy Note 10.1 (p4noterf) running Android 4.4
Galaxy Tab3 7.0 (lt02wifi) running Android 4.4
```

**UPDATE:** these users are now reporting that adding this permission *has* stopped the crashing (though I definitely received at least one crash report from the beta version that includes the new permission).  It still begs the question as to why this permission is required.  It seems to relate to modifying the system settings... that isn't really what I need to do, I only need to write to `SharedPreferences`, and some users may be concerned by this permission.  And why only needed for some devices but not others?

Is there a way I can limit granting this permission to only those devices that seem to need it?

Comment: there have been changes to the permission management in Android 'M'. Do you have crash reports for older versions as well?

Comment: Are the crashes on Samsung devices?  I've logged weird crashes where 1 time in 1000 it says the app doesn't have a permission that it clearly does have, and it's always on Samsung devices.

Comment: I agree with @0X0nosugar. Does is crash on M devices only? If you support the runtime permissions (compileSDKVersion and tarketSDKVersion set to 23), then the app crashes if permission is denied and you do not check for permission.

Comment: Looks like the common factor is more 'Samsung' than 'Android M'... these are devices that have reported the crashes: (1) Galaxy Note3 (hlte) running Android 5.0; (2) Galaxy Note 10.1 (p4noterf) running Android 4.4; and (3) Galaxy Tab3 7.0 (lt02wifi) running Android 4.4 (question updated with this info)

Comment: so, `don't buy Samsungs, eh?`

Comment: Yep, maybe that's right @injecteer